# how to exclude some block statement from transaction - Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need some statement (that's exist in transaction block) to be executed directly to Database without transaction , example :

```
DB::beginTransaction();

//query A : insert or update to some tables in transaction

//**I need some of the result of (query A) to be saved in Database without transaction**

//insert or update to some tables in transaction

DB::commit();
```

Comment: Without some actual code it's difficult to think of a general case in which a non-transactional query is needed inside a transaction. Could you add more details to your question, to me it sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: This question has already been answered, but anyway, the whole point of using transactions is that, if something happens, you can rollback to the original state. If you will update the database , regardless something happens or not, so don't use transactions at all.

Comment: @JoseHenriqueFelipetto I need some result of rows added in transaction and insert it in DB without transaction no mater if transaction rolled back or committed.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT] After reading your question again, it seems i may have misundersood some parts.  If by saying

> I need some of the result of (query A) to be saved in Database without transaction

You mean "use the values inserted within the transaction before the transaction end", i guess it's not possible. You can still use my answer to insert or update data instantaneously, but you'll not be able to *read* something you inserted in the transaction before the transaction end.

---

You can duplicate the connection you are using for the transaction in `database.php`. For this example, let's assume you call it `'mysql_outside_transaction'`. You should have something like this in the `database.php` file, after your default connection:

```
'mysql_outside_transaction' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

From there, since you have a second connection to the same database available, you can use it to save the data you need directly within the transaction.

Again, to make an example, if you have a instance of `$modelA`, you can tell it to use your second connection: `$modelA->setConnection('mysql_outside_transaction');`. From there, every database operation originating from this instance will be done outside your transaction (because it'll use the second connection you configured and not the one used for the transaction).

Don't forget you can set the connection to use in many ways. It could be directly on model class attributes (`protected $connection = 'your_connection';`), with the `DB` facade (`DB::connection('your_connection');`) and probably in other ways i don't think about right now :)

Comment: thanks for your answer , but why I'm getting this error when trying to update value in another connection :
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction.

Comment: Hard to say without an actual piece of code. Are you updating the same row twice, once with a transaction and another time with the non transactional connection (all that within a transaction)? Transactions can get tricky if you are executing queries on related things (like modifying the same row at the same time, that kind of stuff).

Comment: yes I'm updating the same raw twice in the way of your answer ( set another connection to avoid transaction ) !

Comment: Ok that's why it fails. The actual case where i needed something like you was when i tried to update an import status during a long data import. The data import was handled by a transaction so i couldn't update the `import` model directly, that's why i found the workaround explained in my answer. But in my case, the two tables where not directly related.


For what i know, what you are trying to do is impossible since the row you are trying to update is locked when you start the transaction. I could be wrong, nobody knows everything, but i really doubt you can do it (at least with MySQL) :/

Comment: Are you saying that you want it to behave like a checkpoint for queryA and queryB, but not queryC? For example queryC you want it to be rollbackable when errors happen but A and B you want them to be saved.